# Template page css overriding my original css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have template page template.html with css, css includes body{ font-family:'Arial'}. This page included in my application using 'ng-include' when page renders my applications fonts get changed.
can i prevent my application's css to be overridden my template page ..?

Comment: can you not wrap the contents with a div then give the div a class instead of using the body tag.

Comment: contents includes html body tag it's self and has its own CSS. i just want to render that page in my application without affecting my application's CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your Template.html in a div and you can use inline css or css in that page near that div.

you can do like this

```
<div style="font-family:'YourNewFontHere'">

// include your html page here 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is inline styles in the template.html?
One possibility would be to increase the strength of you css rules in your normal page. For example, we assume you have a wrapper div (or s.th. similar) around your content, then you could set:

```
body .wrapper {
  whatever styles you want
}
```

This would override the style from template.html.

You could also add !important to your normal css rules you do not want to be overwritten.

Best of all would be to remove any style-tags from the template.html - why do you style this page inline?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing on the header of your html file.

```
<style> body { font-family: 'Arial'; } </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to increase the specificity of your application's CSS selector for the `<body>` tag. Which shouldn't be too hard since your template is overriding your application's CSS with a simple selector of `body { ... }`.

Couple of ideas.

1. For your application's `<body>` selection change from `body { ... }` to `html body { ... }`.
2. Add a class to the `<body>` tag, `<body class="site">`. Then change `body { ... }` to `.site { ... }`.
3. Remove the `body { ... }` from the template.

Comment: Template page is HTML string like email body which has its own css. when include this in my application i don't know what css that page have because its generated dynamically. After page rendered i come to know that my css is overridden

Comment: What does that have to do with my answers? If you cannot modify the template because it is dynamic then option #3 will not work for you. Try options #1 and #2 for your application's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Template page is HTML string like email body which has its own css. when include this in my application i don't know what css that page have because its generated dynamically. After page rendered i come to know that my css is overridden

Comment: you should edit your original question to add more detail. Could you not post some code snippets to give more of an idea what you are trying to explain?